# How to show all committed-but-not-pushed-yet content in Git?

Tags: git, filter, logging

Time passes, and commits accumulate on my branch. How can I review the changes that piled up in my branch, before pushing them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want to diff the two branches local and remote with the same name.

```
git diff <localbranch> <remote tracking branch>
```

for example:

```
git diff master origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on the branch on which you have been committing:

1. To list the commits only (without the diff) - `git log @{u}..`
2. To list the commits with the diff - `git log -p @{u}..`

Yes, the commands end with two dots. I am not missing anything. :)

For people coming from mercurial, this is **roughly** equal to `hg outgoing`

Answer (score 0):

Try `git reflog`

Before `git push` result will be like:

```
... (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: commit: ...
... (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: commit: ...
```

After:

```
... (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: commit: ...
... HEAD@{1}: commit: ...
```